# Divide two values in bigcommerce

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

does anyone know if it's possible to divide two values?

For example:

product price / unit price = wanted result

Product price:

```
      {{price.without_tax.formatted}}
```

A filter for unit price

```
      {{#filter custom_fields 'Units per case' property='name'}}
      <p>{{ value}}</p>
      {{/filter}}
```

If I am to use something like:

```
    {{#filter custom_fields 'Units per case' property='name'}}
           <p>{{toFixed price.without_tax.formatted divide value}}</p>
     {{/filter}}
```

I get a 0. If I don't include toFixed then nothing shows up. Not sure how to proceed. Please help.

(I know this is some crazy code but I don't know better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a number of issues. Try this:

```
{{#filter custom_fields 'Units per case' property='name'}}
       <p>{{toFixed (divide ../price.without_tax.value value) 2}}</p>
{{/filter}}
```

- Use `price.without_tax.value` instead of `price.without_tax.formatted` so it returns a number instead of a string.
- Add `../` to the price object since it is nested inside `{{filter}}`.
- The divide syntax is `{{divide a b}}`.
- I added a parameter "2" to `{{toFixed}}` so it shows the result with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've messed this up, for sure! I appreciate your help and that you explained things so I can read up on this.